# How to use the "%bag-of" primitive inside a predicate in Racklog

Tags: scheme, racket

This time my problem is mostly with Racklog. I guess. Could also be the Racket syntax this time.

The idea is rather simple. I have a logic-base made up of places and objects and I just wanted to try out printing all the objects using the %bag-of primitive.

My logic-base looks like this:

```
(define %contains
  (%rel ()
      [('bridge 'phaser)]
      [('engine_room 'toolkit)]
      [('toolkit 'screwdriver)]
      [('toolkit 'tricorder)]
      [('inventory '(communicator, no_tea))]
     )
  )
```

Now I have my predicate which is the following one. It should be simply called with the query "(%which () (%list_objects 'toolkit))" and then give out all the items inside the toolkit for example.

```
(define %list_objects
  (%rel (place)
    [(place)
     (%which (objects)
       (%let (x)
           (%bag-of x (%contains place x)
               objects)))]
    )
  )
```

The weird thing is when I just thake the part from the "%which (objects)...)" onwards and throw it directly into the listener, it works perfectly fine. But if I'm using it inside the predicate, it throws this exception:

```
"application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '((objects screwdriver tricorder))
  arguments...: [none]"
```

I tried rearranging the code several times, but right now I'm quite stumped about what I did wrong. I would appreciate a little hint what I as a total newbee to Scheme and Racket missed out here. My thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you enter to provoke the error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the goal `(%which ...)` returns an answer (not a new relation). Therefore `%list_objects` can't be used in the way you want.

Maybe this works for you?

```
#lang racket
(require racklog)

(define %contains
  (%rel ()
        [('bridge      'phaser)]
        [('engine_room 'toolkit)]
        [('toolkit     'screwdriver)]
        [('toolkit     'tricorder)]
        [('inventory   '(communicator, no_tea))]))

(define %list_objects
  (%rel (place)
        [(place)
         (%let (x) (%contains place x))]))

(%which (x) (%list_objects x))
(%more)
(%which (bag) (%let (x) (%bag-of x (%list_objects x) bag)))

(define tools-in-toolkit (map cdar (%find-all (tool) (%contains 'toolkit tool))))

(define %in-toolkit
  (%rel (tool)
        [(tool) (%member tool tools-in-toolkit)]))

(%find-all (tool) (%in-toolkit tool))
```

Output:

```
'((x . bridge))
'((x . engine_room))
'((bag bridge engine_room toolkit toolkit inventory))
'(((tool . screwdriver)) ((tool . tricorder)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer so far. I see your point that "&which" is only meant for the listener. But as far as I understand from the glossary "%bag-of" returns a contract for goals instead of an answer. So is there really no way to use it inside a predicate?

Comment: @DschehutiNefer I have added an example where `%member` is used in a predicate. It would be better to use `(%contains 'toolkit tool)` directly though.